# Polymorphism based function returns None

Tags: python, class, oop, polymorphism

I've been trying to test out Polymorphism in Python
and for some reason my function returns None.
Can you see the reason in the following code? Thanks in advance

```
class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_sound(self):
        return self.__sound

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall {} kg and says {}".format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound)

cat = Animal("Whiskers", 33, 10, "Meow")
```

-- Dog Class:

```
class Dog(Animal):
    __owner = ""

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        self.__owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def get_sound(self):
        return "Woff!"

    def toString(self):
        return "Overriden"

shnitzel = Dog("Shnitzel", 10, 15, 0, "CodingCode")
```

Testing Class:

```
class AnimalTesting:
    def get_sound(self, animal):
        animal.get_sound()

    test_animals = AnimalTesting()
    print test_animals.get_sound(cat)
```

The line: `print test_animals.get_sound(cat)`
returns `None`
Thanks again all!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's pretty simple and has nothing to do with polymorphism whatsoever.  You just forgot a `return`:

```
class AnimalTesting:
    def get_sound(self, animal):
        return animal.get_sound()
```